# Subtracting two pandas series with same index is giving NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

I have two series, both of which have datetime.time indices from 00:00 - 00:05. 
There is 1 missing values in the first series, which ideally should appear NaN after subtraction operation is performed. However, the entire result is NaN. 
I am using series.sub to perform this subtraction.

But this operation is giving NaN values for all columns.

```
print(s8)
time
00:00:00    12.697916
00:01:00    12.062659
00:02:00    11.956684
00:04:00    12.818977
00:05:00    12.309423

print(f8) 
time
00:00:00    14.551911
00:01:00    14.392418
00:02:00    14.488430
00:03:00    14.542103
00:04:00    14.397826  

delta = f8.sub(s8)
print(delta)  

time
00:00:00   NaN
00:01:00   NaN
00:02:00   NaN
00:03:00   NaN
00:04:00   NaN
00:05:00   NaN
```

Ideally it should be,

```
time
00:00:00   2.1
00:01:00   2.0
00:02:00   1.5
00:03:00   1.2
00:04:00   NaN
00:05:00   NaN
```

The ideal values above are just estimate of the subtraction. Please advise how this can b fixed.

Comment: What's the dtype of the value columns?

Comment: f8.sub(s8,fill_value=0)

Comment: @Wen-Ben It doesn't work. It is producing the following dataframe. 
`time
00:00:00    12.697916
00:01:00    12.062659
00:02:00    11.956684
00:03:00    12.818977
00:04:00    12.309423
00:05:00    12.875538
00:06:00    12.350637
00:07:00    12.169571
00:00:00   -14.551911
00:01:00   -14.392418
00:02:00   -14.488430
00:03:00   -14.542103
00:04:00   -14.397826
00:05:00   -14.319630
00:06:00   -14.179186
00:07:00   -14.227638
Name: total, dtype: float64`

Comment: @drum Yes, one of the indices was in string format. Fixed it and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution based on the comments:

Check the column dtypes. As in your case, they were string instead of a numeric one.